# Is there an idiom that means something is inconsistent with the contexts or facts?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means something is inconsistent with the contexts or facts? Like when a book is written and the plot and the world-building doesn't go hand in hand and are inconsistent with each other. Is there an idiom we can use to describe such situations?

Comment: Closest I can think off the top of my head is "it doesn't add up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a few idioms, words or sayings you could use.

- An inconsistency between tone and content might be described as "not in keeping with" (eg "*the tone is not in keeping with the content*") You might also say "*out of harmony with*".
- "It sticks out like a sore thumb" or "it stands out a mile" are both sayings that can refer to anything which is *out of place*.
- Something appearing out of place might be described as "alien", "awkward", or it might be said to "clash" with other things or details.
- Something *inconsistent* might also be said to be "amiss", or "aberrant" (great word, not often used though)

Answer (score 0):

One possible idiom is:

- [out of kilter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_kilter) / [off-kilter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off-kilter): strange, odd; out of order

Although not idioms, these words could be helpful:

- [anachronistic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anachronistic): something out of time, like a Roman wearing a wristwatch
- [discontinuity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discontinuity): a break in continuity